# Converting Unix timestamp (NSTimeInterval) to NSDate is inconsistent on different devices

Tags: ios, nsdate, nstimeinterval

I have an entry with the Unix timestamp of `1408741598`.

```
+ (NSString*)dateTimeToString:(NSDate*)date
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"HHmmss_SSS"];

    return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:date];
}

NSString *time = [FTDateUtils dateTimeToString:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[event timestamp]]];
```

The variable `time` is different on iPad and iPhone.

On one device its `220638_000` and on the other its `220638_517`.

Why the discrepancy here? What can I do?

Comment: Are they set to different timezones?

Comment: Actually it appears they are only 517 milliseconds different? Are you sure the event's timestamp is identical between the devices?

Comment: Break the compound statement into it's components. NSLog `[event timestamp]`, the result of `dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970` and `time`, add that info to the question. You need to know if the error is with the timestamp, NSDatw (unlikely) or FTDateUtils.